# In bash, why does which show the wrong path?

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say, I have the following structure:

```
/usr/bin/app
/home/me/bin/app
```

And `$/usr/bin/app --version` --> `v1`, `$/home/me/bin/app --version` --> `v2`.

So, when I execute some command, say `$app --version`, it returns `v1`, but my `$which app` gives me `/home/me/bin/app`, so, as I think, it must execute the second app, and return `v2`. Why doesn't it happen?

In other words does the construction `$app` equivivalent to `$$(which app)`, and for which reason it doesn't apply ?

Comment: try deleting your app with `hash -d app` and add your app again

Comment: thanks, that works! Suggest you to make the comment to be an answer, so I can `accept` it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `which` takes the hashed value from the [linux hash table](http://webtools.live2support.com/linux/hash.php), when you installed a new executable with the same name, the shell still continues to use the old table, so then it brings a conflict. Instead of using `hash -d <appname>` (which worked), you can also use [rehash](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html) command I believe. (and you should also use zsh, it's very cool :) )